# I cant understant why the delete button does not work for me in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

This is my code:
AdminDelete.jsp:

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
String uid = session.getAttribute("uid").toString();     
String content = request.getParameter("content");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/upload_hub",
        "root", "root");


Statement st = con.createStatement();
int t= st.executeUpdate("DELETE * FROM post WHERE(uid like'"+uid+"' AND content like'"+content+"')");
if(t>0){
    response.sendRedirect("../Admin.jsp");
}

%>
```

this is in the Admin's index:

```
<form method="send" action="functions/AdminDelete.jsp" >
    <h3>delete all posts:</h3>
    <%  String content = request.getParameter("content");%>
    <input type="button" value="delete" id="content">

     </form>
```

I am trying to make a button that when i'm clicking on it, it delete's all of the posts in my website but when i click it, it dosen't do anything

Comment: Do not use jdbc directly in the jsp. Learn about 3tier architecture.

Comment: Also learn about prepared Statements to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Its a school project and it's not going to be live, sql injection is not needed

Comment: Run the query normally using any client tool. Your query may not be satisfying any results. You have used `like` clause but probably you forgot to add `%` wildcard to match record. Also do not forget to close the connection in this way.

Comment: I really did not understand what you mean by saying your comment

Comment: I mean to say suppose you are using MySql database. And using workbench as client tool. Now run query `SELECT * FROM POSTS WHERE UID LIKE 'form_input' and CONTENT LIKE 'form_input'`. Where `form_input` is the value what you submitted in UI form. It will not return any result. That is why you are not able to delete any thing. Instead you may want to use `WHERE UID LIKE '%form_input%' AND CONTENT LIKE '%form_input%'`, which will have some results.

Comment: I also see that you have not added space character after `like` keyword. Check that out too.

Comment: I did what you told me, fixed the space character after the like keyword but it still wont do a thing:



Statement st = con.createStatement();
int t= st.executeUpdate("DELETE * FROM post WHERE UID LIKE '%uid%' AND CONTENT LIKE '%content%'");
if(t>0){
 response.sendRedirect("../Admin.jsp");
}

Comment: Did the select query returned results with your form parameters as I mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: yes i did what you told me to do and its still wont work

Comment: Did select query returned results? You are not clearly answering, that is why I can not understand where you have reached for its solution.

Comment: it does not return anything i checked in the sql and all of the posts are still there

Comment: Yes that is the reason the delete query is not deleting anything. You need to provide the plain sql query you are running. and atlesst one record which must satisfy the Select query with screen shot. You can also try query with one `Where` condition. I mean first with `UID LIKE ...` alone than `COMMENT LIKE ....` alone. It may be some character in form query which makes the select query not able to satisfy.

Comment: i did what you told me to do and it still wont work:



**Statement st = con.createStatement();
int t= st.executeUpdate("DELETE * FROM post WHERE UID LIKE '%uid%' AND WHERE CONTENT LIKE '%content%'");
if(t>0){
 response.sendRedirect("../Admin.jsp");
}**

Answer (score 0):

I can not write entire answer in comment. So writing answer. As I mentioned in comment. You need to add space after `LIKE`. Also using `PreparedStatement`.

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<% String uid = session.getAttribute("uid").toString();
String content = request.getParameter("content");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/upload_hub", "root", "root"); 
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM post WHERE uid like ? AND content LIKE ?"); 
ps.setString(1, "%" + uid + "%");
ps.setString(2, "%" + content + "%");
int t= ps.executeUpdate(); 
try {
    con.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if(t>0){
    response.sendRedirect("../Admin.jsp"); 
} 
%>
```

One thing to note here is that you need to verify the `UID` is set in `session` and  `content` is set in request parameters.

Also you have used `method="send"`. Instead use `method="POST"`.

```
<form method="POST" action="functions/AdminDelete.jsp" > 
    <h3>delete all posts:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="content" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Suppose one record in DB has UID containing letter `a` and corresponding to this record `content` has value containing `b`. Now submit data with `b` as input in form and make sure UID in session has value set to `a`. It should work. If you come up with any error message let me know.

Comment: i did not understand what you mean by saying this: **Suppose one record in DB has UID containing letter a and corresponding to this record content has value containing b. Now submit data with b as input in form and make sure UID in session has value set to a. It should work. If you come up with any error message let me know.**

Comment: There is `POST` table in your DB. It has atleast 2 columns `UID` and `content`. Now Suppose a record in data base has UID = <Some word containing letter a> and content = <some word containing letter `b`. This is what I mean. Now from the UI form you submit letter `b` and because you are picking `UID` from `sesaion` so make sure it has value set to letter `a`. Did you got my point?

Comment: Now when i run the program and click the delete button it says that there is a problem with this method: **e.printStackTtace();**

Comment: I have fixed the typo now.

Comment: Now it says that there is a problem in AdminDelete.jsp in line 7:
 **ps.setString(1, "%" + uid + "%");**

Comment: Can you provide screen shot. I do not see any problem there with `setString()` method. Also please confirm the `uid` variable has right value set.

Comment: how do i send here a print screen?

Comment: Use imgur.com or you can edit the question and add the image.

Comment: its just saying this:

**org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /functions/AdminDelete.jsp at line 8

5: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
6: Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/upload_hub", "root", "root"); 
7: PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM post WHERE uid like "+uid+" AND content LIKE "+content+""); 
8: ps.setString(1, "%" + uid + "%");
9: ps.setString(2, "%" + content + "%");
10: int t= ps.executeUpdate(); 
11: try {**

Comment: and yes i set uid to be "a"

Comment: You are not using my code. Use my code as per answer. The error is because you are using your own code for PreparedStatement and trying to set parameter.

Comment: so you mean i need to separate the **("DELETE FROM post WHERE uid like "+uid+" AND content LIKE "+content+"")**
to uid in one variable and content in a second variable?

Comment: i used your code exactly as you told me to i dont understand

Comment: No, I have used PreparedStatement with ? placeholder

Comment: ok its working but after i delete all the post its just redirecting me to AdminDelete, but i told it to redirect me to Admin.jsp

Comment: Check the console. May be ../Admin.jsp is not correct path. Or if path is Ok. Than may be it is not sending any content in response

Comment: it's telling me this:
**Wed Jan 17 12:38:49 IST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.**

Comment: That is not a problem. Add Admin.jsp page content here. May be it is not sending any output

Comment: No no. Please provide the page content here. It may not sending output. Directly hit the Admin.jsp. Check if it is showing any content. May be it is not sending any output

Comment: i posted the Admin.jsp page take a look its in a different answer